# How to exclusively lock Oracle DB Table using C#?

Tags: c#, oracle

Actually I want to apply lock on a table so that no other process can perform DML(Insert/Update/Delete but can perform Select) or lock that table while 'process execution'.

`LOCK TABLE table-name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`

how should i write that in C#?

// ..... process execution .......

How to Release lock? I guess by either commiting or roll back.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's work around for this issue by exploiting another strategy. Neither solving it through:

1. **EXCLUSIVE LOCKING** (Because I realized if there's another transaction updated my table while my process was underway, that could not update table due to the Lock but as soon as my process completes,means Lock now released, and if another transaction is still on hold then that another transaction will immediately update my table. And that would not bear fruits for me.)Nor solving it through:
2. **IsolationLevel.Serializable** (As the serializable transaction isolation level is not supported with distributed transactions.)

Therefore, on every entry in my table I identify if there is any transaction(whether distributed or local) blocking my table. If there is one, i identify that session and forcefully kill that session. Which perfectly suits my scenario:

```
Database db = DataRepository.GetDatabase();

int result, session_id = 0;
string kill_session, serial = null;
string chk_lock = "SELECT l.session_id,v.serial# ,"
                +"object_name FROM dba_objects o, gv$locked_object l, "
                +"v$session v WHERE o.object_id = l.object_id and "
                +"l.SESSION_ID=v.sid";
DbDataReader rdr_blkAccount;
try{
    //MY PROCESS RUNS HERE...
}
catch(Exception excep)
{
    //...
}
finally
{
    rdr_blkAccount = db.ExecuteReader(chk_lock);

    while (rdr_blkAccount.Read())
    {
        if (rdr_blkAccount[2].ToString().ToUpper() == "ACCOUNT")
        {
            session_id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr_blkAccount[0]);
            serial = session_id.ToString() + ','
                   + Convert.ToInt32(rdr_blkAccount[1]).ToString();
            kill_session = "alter system kill session '" + serial + "'";
            result = db.ExecuteNonQuery(kill_session);
            logger.Log( LogLevel.Warning 
                      , string.Format("Session_id '{0}' has been forcefully killed"
                                     , serial));
        }
    }
    rdr_blkAccount.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lock will be relased on commit or rollback

```
OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection("Data Source=datasrc;User=USER;Password=passwd");
conn.Open();
OracleTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LOCK TABLE TABLE_NAME IN EXCLUSIVE MODE",conn,tr);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.ReadLine();
tr.Commit();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: But i just found on msdn: ExecuteNonQuery does not use a cursor, and therefore does not place locks on the database. If you are issuing a command that requires a lock, do not use ExecuteNonQuery. Instead, use ExecuteReader. How to use that?? Besides, executenonquery returns 0 in my case.. But its written on msdn: For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other DML statements, the return value is -1

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to lock a table?
May be it's enough to specify isolation level using transaction scope object?
For example

```
TransactionOptions TransOpt = New TransactionOptions();
TransOpt.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransOptions))
{
...
}
```

Please, check your requirements.

Comment: Yes isolation is a good option... But now i have another problem. In transaction scope i am getting error: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B). It was missing oramts.dll which i had dowmloaded. I googled this error and found that its because of BIT of dll file. My Oracle client is 64 bit therefore it might be expecting oramts.dll to be 64 bit. From where could i get this?

Comment: It seems to me you can be helped by this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843044

Comment: @knagaev link's dead, bayb, link's dead ... (pulp fiction reference ... nevermind)

Comment: @Noctis you nicked it :) Do you have some necroposting, huh?

Comment: @knagaev barely 2.5 years ... that's not necroposting ... it's still warm ... here, touch it ... the usual mate. have problem, google, SO, follow links, find some dead stuff, help the community by raising awareness ... :)

Comment: @Noctis Ok, I think reinstall oracle (or oracle client) with checked Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server will help with this problem.